# What is the best regular expression to check if a string is function f(x,y,z.......)

Tags: java, regex, expression

What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a function, like this: `f(x,y,z.......`

Comment: The best regex is the one that most closely matches your use case. As it stands, your question is too vague and requires us to make many assumptions. By accurately defining the problem you can get a "better" regex.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like `f\([0-9A-z\,\s]*\)` but then again it depends on your actual use case ...

Comment: thnks :i want regexp in java

Answer (score 1):

`f\(((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\[A-z\]\w*))(,\s*((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\[A-z\]\w*)))*\)`

---

Can handle:

> **1)** Values directly: `f(3.14)`
>   **2)** Complex parameter names: `f(initial_Position_1)`
>   **3)** Single parameter functions: `f(x)`
>   **4)** Multi-parameter functions (n): `f(x, y, z)`
>   **5)** Parameters without space separators: `f(x,y,z)`
>   **(*) Or any combination of the above.**

---

And will guard (fail) against:

> **1)** Parameters that are not valid values or have names starting with digits (invalid): `f(3camelKings)`
>   **2)** Parameters not obeying format rules (typos): `f(x y z)`, `f(x, , z)`, etc...
>   **3)** Null parameters: `f()`

---

### See it in action ***[here](https://regex101.com/r/rWERTs/1)***.

---

### Update:

To make the regex work in Java, just duplicate the `\` characters (`\\`).

This is necessary because Java interprets single `\` as a escape character, and the regex interpreter expects `\` in string format. Meaning that, to have the interpreter receive `"\"` (`\` as string), the string you pass to the regex interpreter should use `\\`.